# Can I check if Disc Level Encryption is enabled on the device with my Android app?

Tags: android

As part of my app can contain PII, i would like to verify that the device is utilizing Device level encryption. Is this something I can check through my app? I've not seen a good way of knowing (and i know the point is that the software is unaware)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [`getStorageEncryptionStatus()` on `DevicePolicyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#getStorageEncryptionStatus%28%29). It is possible that you need to actually be a device admin to do this, but I think anyone can call this method.